# Get opengl version supported on linux machine

Tags: linux, opengl, glew

I am trying to get the opengl version supported on my linux machines.I have a linux machine which have glxinfo output as

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

I think this means that it supports opengl upto 2.1. Now when I check for Opengl 3.1 version `glewIsSupported(GL_VERSION_3_1)` and `glewIsSupported(GL_VERSION_3_2)`it returns true. but it return false for `glewIsSupported(GL_VERSION_3_3)`.     `glxewIsSupported(GLX_ARB_create_context)`  also returns true. I also checked

for some extension which were added in opengl 3.1 like

```
glewIsSupported("GL_ARB_copy_buffer")        : returns true
glewIsSupported("GL_ARB_draw_instanced")     : returns true
```

for some extension which were added in opengl 3.2 like

```
glewIsSupported("GL_ARB_depth_clamp")     :  returns true
```

for some extension which were added in opengl 3.3 like

```
glewIsSupported("GL_ARB_blend_func_extended")   : returns false
```

So does this means means this machine supports opengl 3.2, but then why does glxinfo return it support 2.1. I also tried create oepngl 3.1 forward compatible context, but it fails with following error. So I am assuming that this does not support opengl 3.1.

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  52
  Current serial number in output stream:  51
```

I  have one more machine which has

```
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 5450
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12798 Compatibility Profile Context 13.35.1005
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.30
```

It gives pass for all the extensions. This makes sense I think. But I still dont understand the behavior of first machine.

Basically what I am trying to do is reproduce the condition that first machine does not support opengl 3.1 forward compatibility profile and the second machine does using `GLEW` as I dont know any other way of doing it. Any help?

Note: I need to check for forward compatible profile or core profile. I asked a similar question earlier but this one is much more informative. So sorry for repeating the question

ldd -> glxinfo

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3b5cc000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007faa836f2000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007faa833bd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007faa82fff000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007faa82dd8000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007faa82bc7000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007faa829c4000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007faa827be000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007faa825bc000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007faa823a5000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007faa821a0000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007faa81f82000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007faa81d7d000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007faa81b72000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007faa81955000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007faa81751000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faa83956000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007faa8154e000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007faa81348000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007faa81140000)
```

ldd->my program

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffef7c7a000)
libmaptype.so => /home/oemtest/mapping/dev/cook_126275//bin/libmaptype.so (0x00007f590b814000)
libpng.so => /home/oemtest/mapping/dev/cook_126275//bin/libpng.so (0x00007f590b5dd000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f590b379000)
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f590b10b000)
libglut.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 (0x00007f590aec5000)
libGLEW.so.1.5 => /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.5 (0x00007f590ac6f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f590a973000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f590a673000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f590a45d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f590a09f000)
zlib.so => /home/oemtest/mapping/dev/cook_126275//bin/zlib.so (0x00007f5909e8a000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f5909c63000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f5909a52000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f590984f000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f5909649000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f5909447000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f5909112000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f5908efb000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f5908cf6000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f5908ad8000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f59088d3000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f59086c8000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f59084ab000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f59082a7000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f590bb77000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f59080a4000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f5907e9e000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5907c96000)
```

I have one more machine which have glxinfo output as

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G45/G43 x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.2.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
```

Its behavior is similar to the first machine. Also yes, the first machine was a VM. But this new machine is not VM and is physical machine. This is pastebin for full glxinfo log for this new machine http://pastebin.com/hqEPzCPV

```
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(/*GLUT_DEPTH |*/ GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(m_pngWidth, m_pngHeight);
    int winID = glutCreateWindow("osm2png");


    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        return OPENGL_VERSION_UNSUPPORTED;
    }

    //This shows that it supports opengl version 3.1. 
    if (glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_3_1"))
                openglDriverType = MT_GLSL_3_1;
            else
                return OPENGL_VERSION_UNSUPPORTED;
#else
            return OPENGL_VERSION_UNSUPPORTED;
```

Comment: Can you pastebin the complete glxinfo output of the first machine?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tFC87mK4

Comment: @peppe done please check

Comment: glxinfo on the first machine is reporting that the vendor is VMWare, a virtual machine emulator, and the renderer as Gallium with llvmpipe, which is software-only OpenGL. Can you run ldd on the glxinfo binary and then your program and see if they're linking with different libGL?

Comment: They are linking to same libGL. I have updated the question with ldd for both glxingo and my library

Comment: @HughFisher: VMWare acquired tungsten graphics years ago, which is a main contributor to the mesa3d open source graphics stack. It is perfectly normal for mesa to report VMWare as the vendor, especially when using mesa's built-in software renderer, and does not necessarily mean that this is running inside a VM.

Comment: @PankajBansal: mesa's llvmpipe driver is a CPU-only software rasterizer, and it does support GL3.3. Your mesa version is a bit outdated, though. The llvmpipe driver officialy was at 2.1 for a long time. However, it did support almost everything from 3.x, especially everything which was added in 3.1. It just didn't support one particular feature GL 3.0. You might also just shoot yourself in the foot by setting `glewExperimental`.

Comment: @derhass Thanks for that! I'd never seen VMWare reported as the vendor on any native system of mine, hence my mistake.

Comment: @derhass I have already set the glewExperimental true. I am creating the context using the glut. I have pasted the code. Also as you said llvmpipe is a driver which supports all of 3.1 features, why cant I create a OpenGL 3.1 forward compatible profile. Why does it give me opcode error and why does glxinfo always shows 2.1 version

Comment: @PankajBansal: "I have already set the glewExperimental true." That is exactly the issue I tried to warn you from. You shouldn't just set some features which have "Experimental" in their name if you don't know exactly what they do - this one actually breaks the whole `glewIsSupported` logic - on purpose.

Comment: @PankajBansal: You can't request a 3.1 context because of two reasons: a) mesa generally doesn't support 3.1. You have to request >= 3.2 core profile if you want modern GL on mesa. But this won't help in your case, because b) your implementation doesn't support GL 3.x. I did **not** say that your implementation "supports all of 3.1 features". I did say that it supports "everything which was added in 3.1". It is lacking a feature from GL3.0, as a result, it will be unable to provide you a context > 2.1. You still can use all of those 3.1 stuff via extensions.